# C++ two libraries depend on same lib but different versions?

Tags: c++, gcc, dependencies

If i have libs A, B and C in C++ using GCC compiler. Lib A and B both depend on C but on different versions of it. Can i then use A and B together in another program? or will the different versions required of C by A and B conflict? And how do i resolve this and can i?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're linking dynamically. If both A and B completely encapsulate their respective versions of C then it might be possible to do this. You might have to make sure that the different versions of C are named differently (i.e. libMyC.1.so and libMyC.2.so) to avoid confusion when they are loaded at runtime.

You could also investigate statically building A and B to avoid the possiblility of runtime load confusion.

Simplest way to find out is simply to try it. It shouldn't take to long to determine if it'll work or not.

Lastly, of course, by far the easiest solution, and best from a maintenance perspective is to bring A, or B, up to the level of the other so that they both use the same version of C. This is better in so many ways and I **strongly urge** you to do that rather than to try working around a real problem.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic libraries don't do strong version checking which means that if the entry points that A uses in C haven't changed then it will still be able to use a later version of C.  That being said, often Linux distros use a symbol link filesystem method of providing version support.  This means that if an executable is designed only to work with 1.2.2 then it can be specifically linked to find `/usr/lib/mylib-1.2.2`.

Mostly programs are linked to find the general case, eg. `/usr/lib/mylib` and this will be symbolically linked to the version which is on the machine.  E.g. `/usr/lib/mylib -> /usr/lib/mylib-1.2.2`.   Providing you don't link to a specific version and the actuall interfaces don't change, forward compatibility shouldn't be a problem.

If you want to check whether libraries A and B are bound to a specifically named version of C, you can use the `ldd` command on them to check the dll search path.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question in my searching for answers and as @Component-10 suggested, I have created a minimal set of files to investigate this behavior and tested with MacOS + CLANG.

- If building A and B as shared libraries, you can get the proper resolution to a dependent library, C, to which are dependencies of A and B, but at different versions.
- If building A and B as static, it fails.

**EDIT**

**As pointed out in the comments, the shared library approach is not cross platform and does not work in Linux.**

@SergA has created a solution with the Dynamically Loaded Library (dl) API (https://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/x172.html).

### @SergA's solution using dlopen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

// #define DLOPEN_FLAGS RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL
#define DLOPEN_FLAGS RTLD_LAZY

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
    // Windows (x86 or x64)
    const char* libA = "libA.shared.dll";
    const char* libB = "libB.shared.dll";
#elif defined(__linux__)
    // Linux
    const char* libA = "libA.shared.so";
    const char* libB = "libB.shared.so";
#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    // Mac OS
    const char* libA = "libA.shared.dylib";
    const char* libB = "libB.shared.dylib";
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
    // Unix like OS
    const char* libA = "libA.shared.so";
    const char* libB = "libB.shared.so";
#else
    #error Unknown environment!
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;

  void *handle_A;
  void *handle_B;
  int (*call_A)(void);
  int (*call_B)(void);
  char *error;

  handle_B = dlopen(libB, DLOPEN_FLAGS);
  if(handle_B == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  handle_A = dlopen(libA, DLOPEN_FLAGS);
  if(handle_A == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  call_A = dlsym(handle_A, "call_A");
  error = dlerror();
  if(error != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  call_B = dlsym(handle_B, "call_B");
  error = dlerror();
  if(error != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf(" main_AB->");
  call_A();
  printf(" main_AB->");
  call_B();

  dlclose(handle_B);
  dlclose(handle_A);

  return 0;
}
```

### Previous solution showing static vs. shared

Here is my set of files. I will not show them all here for brevity.

```
$ tree .
.
├── A
│   ├── A.cc
│   └── A.hh
├── B
│   ├── B.cc
│   └── B.hh
├── C
│   ├── v1
│   │   ├── C.cc
│   │   └── C.hh
│   └── v2
│       ├── C.cc
│       └── C.hh
├── compile_shared_works.sh
├── compile_static_fails.sh
├── main_A.cc
├── main_AB.cc
└── main_B.cc
```

A depends on C version 1 and B depends on C version 2. Each library contains a single function, e.g. `libA` contains `call_A` which calls `libC` v1's `call_C`, and `libB` contains `call_B` which calls `libC` v1's `call_C`.

Then `main_A` links to only `libA`, `main_B` to only `lib_B`, and `main_AB` to both.

#### compile_static_fails.sh

The following set of commands builds `libA` and `libB` statically.

```
#clean slate
rm -f *.o *.so *.a *.exe

#generate static libA
g++ -I . -c C/v1/C.cc A/A.cc
ar rvs libA.a *.o
rm -f *.o

#generate static libB
g++ -I . -c C/v2/C.cc B/B.cc
ar rvs libB.a *.o
rm -f *.o

#generate 3 versions of exe
g++ -L . -lA main_A.cc -o main_A.exe
g++ -L . -lB main_B.cc -o main_B.exe
g++ -L . -lA -lB main_AB.cc -o main_AB.exe
./main_A.exe
./main_B.exe
./main_AB.exe
```

The output is

```
main_A->call_A->call_C [v1]
main_B->call_B->call_C [v2]
main_AB->call_A->call_C [v1]
main_AB->call_B->call_C [v1]
```

When `main_AB` executes `call_B` it goes to the wrong place!

#### compile_shared_works.sh

```
#clean slate
rm -f *.o *.so *.a *.exe

#generate shared libA
g++ -I . -c -fPIC C/v1/C.cc A/A.cc
g++ -shared *.o -o libA.so
rm *.o

#generate shared libB
g++ -I . -c -fPIC C/v2/C.cc B/B.cc
g++ -shared *.o -o libB.so
rm *.o

#generate 3 versions of exe
g++ -L . -lA main_A.cc -o main_A.exe
g++ -L . -lB main_B.cc -o main_B.exe
g++ -L . -lA -lB main_AB.cc -o main_AB.exe
./main_A.exe
./main_B.exe
./main_AB.exe
```

The output is

```
main_A->call_A->call_C [v1]
main_B->call_B->call_C [v2]
main_AB->call_A->call_C [v1]
main_AB->call_B->call_C [v2]
```

It works (on MacOS)!

Comment: Hi, can't reproduce your result. I tried to build test samples both with GCC and Clang. In all variants I get wrong result. I think this is coused with different ld.so behaviour on our systems.

Comment: I create test based your answer here: https://github.com/anton-sergeev/multiversion_library_test. I add **dlopen**-variant this works for me.

Comment: Dang. I guess this only works for MacOS/X + CLANG then. I will update answer accordingly.

Comment: Your shared library case would work in Linux as well if you avoid re-exporting libC's symbols in libA and libB (=define the ABI). You can do that with a [version script](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/LD-Version-Scripts.html) for libA and libB (if you don't have control over libC's build scripts / source code), or by specifying visibility directly in libC using `-fvisibility=hidden` or through code annotation `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`.

Answer (score 2):

@SergA's solution also works in Linux if we open the shared library with flag
 **RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL**
The output is:
     1. **Main_AB_dlopen -> CallA -> callC(v1)**
     2. **Main_AB_dlopen -> callB -> callC(v2)**

Comment: RTLD_DEEPBIND is also required

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution by `dlopen(RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND)`
or `dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "filename.so", ...)`
(familiar as other answers above)

First we should read this article to know **.dynsym** is 'exported symbol table' in linux ELF:  https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/post/inside-elf-symbol-tables

Each elf file include executable and dynamic library has **.dynsym** in header. The function declared with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` will recorded in this header zone.
But if the `-fvisibility=hidden` has not assigned to compiler (gcc), all functions would declare with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` by compiler automatically. (all functions marked as export)

#### How's the .so loading?

All .so would be loaded in memory before the program start `int main()`, all file marked as DT_NEEDED in ELF header one by one.
There has a **global symbol table** in system for current program, all .so loadad and fill the address of function name their hold in this table, if two .so file has same function name, only the first one would accepted.

**dlopen()**
The program loaded in `dlopen()` is no difference with loading by ELF header, the **global symbol table** are also filled by `dlopen()`.

For example

```
// main.cpp
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) int fn() { return 10; }
void print();
int main() { print(); return 0; }

// libfn.cpp => libfn.so
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) int fn() { return 999; }
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) void print() { cout<<fn(); }
```

The **10** would print, since the `fn()` in main.cpp would loaded before libfn.so.

If using `dlopen(libfn.so, RTLD_LOCAL)` without `RTLD_DEEPBIND`, the number **10** still would be printed.

If using normal link in compiling stage, even if using something like lib_try_in_middle.so to separate the **.dynsym** in ELF-header, the functions in **any** file marked as `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` always appear in **global symbol table**.

#### Known issue

address sanitizer cannot work with `RTLD_DEEPBIND`, and I haven't found any solution to let asan run in new namespace by `dlmopen()`.

Reference: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html